# How do I parse json key value pairs inside a json object using Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

How do I parse this using Volley

```
{
    "ref": "suc",
    "contactInfo": {
        "name": "Jezzi",
        "age": "3",
        "Place": "Kochi"
    }
}
```

Code in Android

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

   try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     String ref = jsonObject.getString("ref");
    
   } catch (Exception e ) {

       Log.i("Hello", e.toString);
   }
}
```

I'm getting string value ref, but I don't know how to get the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     String ref = jsonObject.getString("ref");
     JSONObject contactJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("contactInfo");
     String name = contactJsonObject.getString("name");
     // and other values like this
   } catch (Exception e ) {

       Log.i("Hello", e.toString);
   }
```

Comment: Error: rg.json.JSONException: Value null at contactInfoof type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: This should be working, Are you sure the json you posted is the right one? and take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) tutorial

Comment: That was right man, Thank you so much. The problem in my case is I'm passing wrong form-data as parameter.... Now I fixed that. and worked well.